# Users with "AddListItems, ViewPages, ViewFormPages, Open" permission are not able to add item to a list

Tags: 2013, permissions, team-sites, custom-properties

I have created the following custom permission, to allow users to be able to add items to a Issue Tracking list, but without being able to edit, read, search them:-

```
$spweb=Get-SPWeb -Identity "Site URL";
$spRoleDefinition = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleDefinition;
$spRoleDefinition.Name = "Submit only";
$spRoleDefinition.Description = "Can submit/add forms/files/items into library or list but cannot view/edit them.";
$spRoleDefinition.BasePermissions = "AddListItems, ViewPages, ViewFormPages, Open";
$spweb.RoleDefinitions.Add($spRoleDefinition);
$spweb.Dispose();
```

But users having this permission level are unable to create new item, and if they click on create item link , they will get the following message:-

"This site has not been shared with you" ?

Can anyone advice please?
Thanks

**EDIT**

I have the following web part inside my visual studio :-

```
 [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public partial class VisualWebPart1 : WebPart
    {
        // Uncomment the following SecurityPermission attribute only when doing Performance Profiling using
        // the Instrumentation method, and then remove the SecurityPermission attribute when the code is ready
        // for production. Because the SecurityPermission attribute bypasses the security check for callers of
        // your constructor, it's not recommended for production purposes.
        // [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, UnmanagedCode = true)]
        public VisualWebPart1()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            InitializeControl();
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPGroup group = web.Groups["Risk Issue Managers"];
        bool isUser = web.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(group.ID);
        if (!isUser)
        {

            SPList myList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Risk & Issue Management");
            SPField titleField = myList.Fields.GetField("Item Type");
            titleField.Hidden = true;
            titleField.ShowInEditForm = false;
            titleField.ShowInNewForm = false;
            titleField.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
            titleField.Update();
            SPField titleField2 = myList.Fields.GetField("Estimated Resolution Date");
            titleField2.Hidden = true;
            titleField2.ShowInEditForm = false;
            titleField2.ShowInNewForm = false;
            titleField2.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
            titleField2.Update();
            SPField titleField3 = myList.Fields.GetField("Project/s No");
            titleField3.Hidden = true;
            titleField3.ShowInEditForm = false;
            titleField3.ShowInNewForm = false;
            titleField3.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
            titleField3.Update();
            SPField titleField4 = myList.Fields.GetField("Current Status");
            titleField4.Hidden = true;
            titleField4.ShowInEditForm = false;
            titleField4.ShowInNewForm = false;
            titleField4.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
            titleField4.Update();
            SPField titleField5 = myList.Fields.GetField("Priority");
            titleField5.Hidden = true;
            titleField5.ShowInEditForm = false;
            titleField5.ShowInNewForm = false;
            titleField5.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
            titleField5.Update();
            SPField titleField6 = myList.Fields.GetField("Related Issues");
            titleField6.Hidden = true;
            titleField6.ShowInEditForm = false;
            titleField6.ShowInNewForm = false;
            titleField6.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
            titleField6.Update();
            myList.Update();
            // web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

        }
        else
        {
            SPList myList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Risk & Issue Management");
            SPField titleField = myList.Fields.GetField("Item Type");
            titleField.Hidden = false;
            titleField.ShowInEditForm = true;
            titleField.ShowInNewForm = true;
            titleField.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
            titleField.Update();
            SPField titleField2 = myList.Fields.GetField("Estimated Resolution Date");
            titleField2.Hidden = false;
            titleField2.ShowInEditForm = true;
            titleField2.ShowInNewForm = true;
            titleField2.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
            titleField2.Update();
            SPField titleField3 = myList.Fields.GetField("Project/s No");
            titleField3.Hidden = false;
            titleField3.ShowInEditForm = true;
            titleField3.ShowInNewForm = true;
            titleField3.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
            titleField3.Update();
            SPField titleField4 = myList.Fields.GetField("Current Status");
            titleField4.Hidden = false;
            titleField4.ShowInEditForm = true;
            titleField4.ShowInNewForm = true;
            titleField4.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
            titleField4.Update();
            SPField titleField5 = myList.Fields.GetField("Priority");
            titleField5.Hidden = false;
            titleField5.ShowInEditForm = true;
            titleField5.ShowInNewForm = true;
            titleField5.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
            titleField5.Update();
            SPField titleField6 = myList.Fields.GetField("Related Issues");
            titleField6.Hidden =false;
            titleField6.ShowInEditForm = true;
            titleField6.ShowInNewForm = true;
            titleField6.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
            titleField6.Update();
            myList.Update();
            //    //web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
});

        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPGroup group = web.Groups["Risk Issue Managers"];
                    bool isUser = web.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(group.ID);
                    if (!isUser)
                    {

                        SPList myList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Risk & Issue Management");
                        SPField titleField = myList.Fields.GetField("Item Type");
                        titleField.Hidden = true;
                        titleField.ShowInEditForm = false;
                        titleField.ShowInNewForm = false;
                        titleField.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
                        titleField.Update();
                        SPField titleField2 = myList.Fields.GetField("Estimated Resolution Date");
                        titleField2.Hidden = true;
                        titleField2.ShowInEditForm = false;
                        titleField2.ShowInNewForm = false;
                        titleField2.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
                        titleField2.Update();
                        SPField titleField3 = myList.Fields.GetField("Project/s No");
                        titleField3.Hidden = true;
                        titleField3.ShowInEditForm = false;
                        titleField3.ShowInNewForm = false;
                        titleField3.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
                        titleField3.Update();
                        SPField titleField4 = myList.Fields.GetField("Current Status");
                        titleField4.Hidden = true;
                        titleField4.ShowInEditForm = false;
                        titleField4.ShowInNewForm = false;
                        titleField4.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
                        titleField4.Update();
                        SPField titleField5 = myList.Fields.GetField("Priority");
                        titleField5.Hidden = true;
                        titleField5.ShowInEditForm = false;
                        titleField5.ShowInNewForm = false;
                        titleField5.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
                        titleField5.Update();
                        SPField titleField6 = myList.Fields.GetField("Related Issues");
                        titleField6.Hidden = true;
                        titleField6.ShowInEditForm = false;
                        titleField6.ShowInNewForm = false;
                        titleField6.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
                        titleField6.Update();
                        myList.Update();
                        // web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SPList myList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Risk & Issue Management");
                        SPField titleField = myList.Fields.GetField("Item Type");
                        titleField.Hidden = false;
                        titleField.ShowInEditForm = true;
                        titleField.ShowInNewForm = true;
                        titleField.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
                        titleField.Update();
                        SPField titleField2 = myList.Fields.GetField("Estimated Resolution Date");
                        titleField2.Hidden = false;
                        titleField2.ShowInEditForm = true;
                        titleField2.ShowInNewForm = true;
                        titleField2.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
                        titleField2.Update();
                        SPField titleField3 = myList.Fields.GetField("Project/s No");
                        titleField3.Hidden = false;
                        titleField3.ShowInEditForm = true;
                        titleField3.ShowInNewForm = true;
                        titleField3.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
                        titleField3.Update();
                        SPField titleField4 = myList.Fields.GetField("Current Status");
                        titleField4.Hidden = false;
                        titleField4.ShowInEditForm = true;
                        titleField4.ShowInNewForm = true;
                        titleField4.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
                        titleField4.Update();
                        SPField titleField5 = myList.Fields.GetField("Priority");
                        titleField5.Hidden = false;
                        titleField5.ShowInEditForm = true;
                        titleField5.ShowInNewForm = true;
                        titleField5.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
                        titleField5.Update();
                        SPField titleField6 = myList.Fields.GetField("Related Issues");
                        titleField6.Hidden = false;
                        titleField6.ShowInEditForm = true;
                        titleField6.ShowInNewForm = true;
                        titleField6.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
                        titleField6.Update();
                        myList.Update();
                        //    //web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

but i am facing these issues:-

- if a user inside the "Risk Issue Manager" group click on create , he will see all the fields, which will be fine.
- but if i remove him from the "Risk Issue Manager" group, then he can still see the fields !!, although inside the web part i mentioned to hide these fields ...

so can anyone advice what is causing this and how to solve it ? could this be related to caching problem? baring in mind that i am displaying the Create form inside a dialog box ? and when the web part is going to run ? each time the user click on Create button?

Comment: are you able to access http://url/_layouts/settings.aspx link?

Comment: yes i can see this

Comment: try copying the the base permissions for "Contribute" role and remove "EditListItems" and "DeleteListItems" from it.

Comment: what will this do ? i mean what is the difference from my approach ?

Comment: also contributors will be able to read item and view list views such as "My submission view" & "Approve/reject" view.. which in my case i want to avoid ... so seems coping from contributor is too much in my case..

Comment: @Unnie can you advice on my above comments?

Comment: As a troubleshooting technique you can copy contributor permissions and remove what is not required one by one

Comment: @Unnie can you please check my edit to the original question, seems now i am facing different problem..

Answer (score 1):

try the below solution:

1. Go to Central Admin. Click on the “Application Management” heading.
2. Click on “Manage services on server”.
3. Stop the service “Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application”. This will take a little while to stop.
4. Start the above service again.

This should resolve the problem.

Comment: why do i need to do so ?

Comment: it keeps showing stopping , and i am unable to start it agian ?

Comment: so there is some problm there in the configuration. if its not starting try IIS reset or restart the machine

Comment: but will this fix the permission issue?

Comment: yes i hope so, you can give it an attempt. won't spoil anything

Comment: ok i restart the whole server, but still users are receving this error :- 'Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you'

Comment: the strange thing is that inside the test server it worked well,, but on the staging server it does not.. the diffirence is that the staging is using sharepoint service pack 1

Comment: could this be related that i need to add the users to the audiences for the web part?

Comment: i don't think so.

Comment: ya i actually changed the audiences to include the visitors group but still did not fix the issue...

Comment: any idea about what is causing my permission settings to not be working, although the permission i gave them sound enough to create new item lists ?? can u advice?

Comment: just let me check will update you

Comment: i am now sure that the problem is within the web part which i added to hide column, because if i remove the web part from the edit for  users will be able to see the new for and they can create new items...

Comment: i run the code inside "SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()" which seems to bypass the suer permission but now i am facing what seems to be a caching problem .. can you check my edit to the original question ?

Comment: this cannot be a caching issue.please check your else loop.